# How can I add-new or modify-existing file template in Xcode4?

Tags: templates, file, xcode4

How can I put a new or modifying existing file template in Xcode4?

Answer (score 3):

I found great article about this: http://blog.red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/making-custom-templates-for-xcode-4-march-2011/